# Cannot feed value of shape (2, 3000, 64) for Tensor vggish/input_features:0, which has shape (None, 96, 64)

Tags: python, tensorflow, audio, deep-learning, neural-network

I am trying adapt Google's [VGGish CNN][1], created for audio analysis. Off the shelf, this model extracts features from 1 second chunks of audio, puts these in a  tuple with one-hot coding to represent class, and trains on this. Any longer files are cut into 1sec chunks if input. I want to instead use 1min chunks, so cutting longer files into 1min chunks if input.

The network runs perfectly when I enter my audio and don't use my modifications (detailed below). With changes I have made, I can also cut longer files into 1min chunks, extract features from these, and save them in a tuple with one-hot coding to be entered into the model for training. However, when I enter this into the model I get the following error:

ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape (2, 3000, 64) for Tensor vggish/input_features:0, which has shape (None, 96, 64)

Looks like I have incorrectly assumed that if I edit the vggish_params and input modules as shown, that it should now accept features from one minute files, or, I have missed something else I need to change. Can anyone advise where I'm going wrong?

**Modifications:**

The key script I have adapted from the models github is [vggish_train_demo][2]. Here I have adapted it to read files, rather than generate the toy example at the start of the original script (see code block 1 below for my changes).

I have also modified 3 variables in the script for the [vggish_params][3] module, and saved this as vggish_params_new:

```
NUM_FRAMES = 3000  #formally 96

EXAMPLE_WINDOW_SECONDS = 30  #formally 0.96

EXAMPLE_HOP_SECONDS = 30  #formally 0.96
```

I have also changed the script for the [vggish_input][4] module to import vggish_params_new at the top, and substituted it in at every point where vggish_params was called. I've renamed this to vggish_input_new and substituted in when its called in code block 2.

**Code block 1:**

```
def get_features(directory):
    all_fs = os.listdir(directory) #list of all files in directory
    audio_fs = [f for f in all_fs if '.wav' in f.lower() or '.mp3' in f.lower()] 
    for f in audio_fs:
        #import mel_features
        path = os.path.join(directory, f)
        features_from_files_list = vggish_input_new.wavfile_to_examples(path)
    features_from_files = np.array(features_from_files_list)
    return features_from_files

def _get_examples_batch(dir1, dir2):  #example using two classes, each stored in a seperate directory                             
   #Get features from audio files and generate one-hot coding for each dir
  
   dir1_feats = get_features(dir1)
   dir1_labels = np.array([[1, 0]] * dir1_feats.shape[0])
   dir2_feats = get_features(dir2)
   dir2_labels = np.array([[0, 1]] * dir2_feats.shape[0])

   #Shuffle (example, label) pairs across all classes.
   all_examples = np.concatenate((dir1_feats, dir2_feats))     
   all_labels = np.concatenate((dir1_labels, dir2_labels))        
   labeled_examples = list(zip(all_examples, all_labels))
   shuffle(labeled_examples)

   #Separate and return the features and labels.
   features = [example for (example, _) in labeled_examples]
   labels = [label for (_, label) in labeled_examples]
   return (features, labels)"""

_NUM_CLASSES = 2
dir1 = (r'C:\Users\class1')
dir2 = (r'C:\Users\class2')

#define sample rate of audio:
sr = 44100
```

**Code block 2:**

```
def main(_):
   with tf.Graph().as_default(), tf.Session() as sess:
     # Define VGGish.
     embeddings = vggish_slim.define_vggish_slim(training=FLAGS.train_vggish)

     # Define a shallow classification model and associated training ops on top
     # of VGGish.
     with tf.variable_scope('mymodel'):
       # Add a fully connected layer with 100 units. Add an activation function
       # to the embeddings since they are pre-activation.
       num_units = 100
       fc = slim.fully_connected(tf.nn.relu(embeddings), num_units)

       # Add a classifier layer at the end, consisting of parallel logistic
       # classifiers, one per class. This allows for multi-class tasks.
       logits = slim.fully_connected(
           fc, _NUM_CLASSES, activation_fn=None, scope='logits')
       tf.sigmoid(logits, name='prediction')

       # Add training ops.
       with tf.variable_scope('train'):
         global_step = tf.train.create_global_step()

         # Labels are assumed to be fed as a batch multi-hot vectors, with
         # a 1 in the position of each positive class label, and 0 elsewhere.
         labels_input = tf.placeholder(
             tf.float32, shape=(None, _NUM_CLASSES), name='labels')

         # Cross-entropy label loss.
         xent = tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits(
             logits=logits, labels=labels_input, name='xent')
         loss = tf.reduce_mean(xent, name='loss_op')
         tf.summary.scalar('loss', loss)

         # We use the same optimizer and hyperparameters as used to train VGGish.
         optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(
             learning_rate=vggish_params_new.LEARNING_RATE,
             epsilon=vggish_params_ben.ADAM_EPSILON)
         train_op = optimizer.minimize(loss, global_step=global_step)

     # Initialize all variables in the model, and then load the pre-trained
     # VGGish checkpoint.
     sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
     vggish_slim.load_vggish_slim_checkpoint(sess, FLAGS.checkpoint)

     # The training loop.
     features_input = sess.graph.get_tensor_by_name(
         vggish_params_ben.INPUT_TENSOR_NAME)
     for _ in range(FLAGS.num_batches):
       (features, labels) = _get_examples_batch(dir1, dir2) #enter required no. dirs   
       [num_steps, loss_value, _] = sess.run(
           [global_step, loss, train_op],
           feed_dict={features_input: features, labels_input: labels})
       print('Step %d: loss %g' % (num_steps, loss_value))

 if __name__ == '__main__':
   tf.app.run()
```

**Full error:**

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_1272/4207831446.py in <module>
     59 
     60 if __name__ == '__main__':
---> 61   tf.app.run()

~\Anaconda3\envs\test-vggishtraining-env\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\platform\app.py in run(main, argv)
     38   main = main or _sys.modules['__main__'].main
     39 
---> 40   _run(main=main, argv=argv, flags_parser=_parse_flags_tolerate_undef)

~\Anaconda3\envs\test-vggishtraining-env\lib\site-packages\absl\app.py in run(main, argv, flags_parser)
    310       callback()
    311     try:
--> 312       _run_main(main, args)
    313     except UsageError as error:
    314       usage(shorthelp=True, detailed_error=error, exitcode=error.exitcode)

~\Anaconda3\envs\test-vggishtraining-env\lib\site-packages\absl\app.py in _run_main(main, argv)
    256     sys.exit(retval)
    257   else:
--> 258     sys.exit(main(argv))
    259 
    260 

~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_1272/4207831446.py in main(_)
     53     for _ in range(FLAGS.num_batches):
     54       (features, labels) = _get_examples_batch(healthy, degraded)    ##################may need to change
---> 55       [num_steps, loss_value, _] = sess.run(
     56           [global_step, loss, train_op],
     57           feed_dict={features_input: features, labels_input: labels})

~\Anaconda3\envs\test-vggishtraining-env\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py in run(self, fetches, feed_dict, options, run_metadata)
    968 
    969     try:
--> 970       result = self._run(None, fetches, feed_dict, options_ptr,
    971                          run_metadata_ptr)
    972       if run_metadata:

~\Anaconda3\envs\test-vggishtraining-env\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py in _run(self, handle, fetches, feed_dict, options, run_metadata)
   1165           if (not is_tensor_handle_feed and
   1166               not subfeed_t.get_shape().is_compatible_with(np_val.shape)):
-> 1167             raise ValueError(
   1168                 f'Cannot feed value of shape {str(np_val.shape)} for Tensor '
   1169                 f'{subfeed_t.name}, which has shape '

ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape (2, 3000, 64) for Tensor vggish/input_features:0, which has shape (None, 96, 64)


  [1]: https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/audioset/vggish
  [2]: https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/audioset/vggish/vggish_train_demo.py
  [3]: https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/audioset/vggish/vggish_params.py
  [4]: https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/audioset/vggish/vggish_input.py
```

Comment: Are you shure you replaced everything properly? It looks like you missed an import, because the input placeholder is still configured for 96 frames. Did you update [this](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/885fda091c46c59d6c7bb5c7e760935eacc229da/research/audioset/vggish/vggish_slim.py#L36) import of the params as well?

Comment: Yupp, you were right! I hadn't spotted vggish_params was called in vggish_slim and hadn't updated this. Fixing this and changing vggish_slim to viggish_slim_new in my second code block fixed this. Now facing new errors but will have a look at these.